# Would a pipe from the surface to the Earth's exosphere suck all atmosphere to the space?

Tags: earth, atmospheric-science, popular-science, fluid-statics

If I built a tube from Earth's surface to the exosphere, would all the air be sucked out to space?

If this pipe reached to a big planet, like Jupiter, would its gravity through the pipe suck our atmosphere?

If one end of the pipe was at the Earth's core, and other in the exosphere, would the magma go there, like in giant volcano?

Comment: Do you understand any of the physics of fluid dynamics? Have you done any research about this? Why do you think the tube might cause this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a list of questions which don't show any effort at research of existing written sources.

Comment: There is vacuum in the space. So it can behave like cocktail with a straw, when you making vacuum with your mouth. About third part: volcanoes trowing magma outside all the time, so why they will not do it through pipe?

Comment: So why do you need a pipe? Why isn't the whole atmosphere sucked off the planet? In other words, why does Earth keep an atmosphere? A pipe changes nothing.

Comment: About first part I had such a thought, but there in question are two more cases...

Comment: 2) Why doesn't Jupiter pull our atmosphere now?

Comment: Same reason the others don't work.  Pipes don't make any difference. Substance doesn't make any difference. Why aren't you and I pulled into space by Jupiter or by ``the vacuum?''  The vacuum is not a force!

Comment: Yes. But gravity and pressure are. So why it can't behave as water in communicating vessels?

Comment: Because the pressure inside the pipe and outside the pipe are identical at every level. There is no net force on the air.  Pressure is the result of gravitational pull on the atmosphere.  Read everything at this link: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/hframe.html

Comment: More on space tubes: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69806/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/155371/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. No, it would not be sucked off, for the same reason that the earth has an atmosphere to begin with: gravity.
2. No, for the same reason that Jupiter doesn't have a noticeable pull on you: the strength gravity decreases with the inverse square of distance.
3. No, Gravity is too strong.

Your misconception seems to be coming from the idea of a vacuum and a straw. The vacuum itself is not what causes the sucking. It is the atmospheric pressure that causes sucking.

[image]

Comment: But what about second and third parts of question?

Comment: Gravity, and gravity.