# Could a big enough straw stretching from Earth to space eject atmosphere into space?

Tags: pressure, earth, atmospheric-science, fluid-statics

Assuming the straw can be built out of any material, shape, size.

Would the vacuum effect of space acting on the pressurized gas have enough force to lift the weight of the atmosphere contained in the straw out into space?

Or maybe the atmosphere is simply to heavy to lift into space?

Would it be similar to a really long straw that reaches down to the deep end of a pool and your standing outside the pool and your trying to suck water through the straw up from out of the bottom. The plastic straw might collapse in on itself from the negative pressure but if it was made from metal it is possible.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/207076/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2):

There would be no net movement of air in such a straw extending from the surface of the Earth to outer space. Perhaps you're thinking that the air at the bottom of the straw is being pushed into the straw with a pressure of 1 atmosphere (14.7 psi) while the top of the straw is at vacuum (0 psi) and so there is a net force pushing the air into outer space? The problem with that reasoning is it neglects the fact that there is the force of gravity acting in the opposite direction. Everything balances out.

Same thing with putting a long straw into a pool of water. Sure, the water pressure at the bottom the the straw may be much larger than that of the water of the top of the straw, but gravity balances everything out (and, in fact, gravity is the reason that there is a pressure differential in the first place for both the atmosphere and the pool of water cases).