# Generating power with a "straw" to space... Is it possible?

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics, atmospheric-science, earth

Imagine you have a straw in a glass of water. If you put a turbine inside it somehow and move the glass, pour water in and out of it etc, you would see the water level rise and fall, and the turbine would spin, generating power.

I'm sure you can see where I'm going with this:

Our atmosphere far from a static glass of water, there are colder and hotter parts that create air flows, that can be very fast, and could output a lot of energy.
So is it possible/feasible to generate energy this way; by placing turbines in a long straw from Earth to space? I know it may not be practical, but is it physically possible?

Similar methods are already being used to harness energy from ocean waves, so i wondered if this would be possible as well.

Comment: Do you mean using a lot of energy to push water up to space?

Comment: No, just a straw filled with Air, should have clarified

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/207076/2451 and links therein.