# 1 mile high tube

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics, bernoulli-equation

It is pretty well known that the atmospheric pressure reduces with altitude. What happens to the airflow if we anchor an imaginary one mile tube near the sea level that has a hole near its base? Does the pressure difference pushes the air up the tube?

Comment: Why would it? It'd be like placing a straw half submerged in water. Same pressure gradients inside ant outside of the tube.

Comment: What's the difference between the "inside" and "outside" of the tube?

Comment: @HessPhys It is a nice question (+1). Please, pay attention, that atmosphere is open system. Therefore, flow in a tube depends on the state of atmosphere - temperature gradient and wind outside. You can use Google  with words "natural draft" to find out how it works.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/207076/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

No - pressure decreases with altitude because of gravity. Gravity would exist inside the tube.

The pressure gradient's force pushing air up would be exactly counteracted by gravity, hence why that pressure gradient exists in the first place.